Iterating through tables/columns in snowflake schema to find text value only working sometimes?
I am working within a snowflake DB schema that has about 200 tables and I need to figure out which table has a specific row-level value within a column. Looking for any table that contains a value = "Alternative Credential" in the rows. I executed this, but it stopped working after the second run:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE find_text_occurrences()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    table_name STRING;
    column_name STRING;
    all_columns CURSOR FOR (
        SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('INFORMATION_SCHEMA', 'YOUR_EXCLUDED_SCHEMA') 
        AND data_type = 'TEXT'
        -- Add more filters if needed
        -- AND table_name IN ('YOUR_TABLE_1', 'YOUR_TABLE_2') -- Filter tables
    );
BEGIN
    -- Create or recreate the temporary table
    CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE discovery_results (
        table_name STRING,
        column_name STRING,
        matches INT
    );

    -- Process columns and tables
    FOR record IN all_columns DO
        table_name := record.table_schema || '.' || record.table_name;
        column_name := record.column_name;

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
            'INSERT INTO discovery_results (table_name, column_name, matches) ' ||
            'SELECT ''' || table_name || ''', ''' || column_name || ''', COUNT(*) ' ||
            'FROM ' || table_name || ' ' ||
            'WHERE ' || column_name || ' LIKE ''%Alternative Credential%'''
        ;
    END FOR;

    RETURN 'Results are available in the discovery_results table. Run SELECT * FROM discovery_results to find the results';
END;
$$;

CALL find_text_occurrences();

SELECT * FROM discovery_results;

On first run, it worked--displaying table and column name and how many row-level matches. When I changed the value to something else, like "Marketing", it displayed
002003 (42S02): SQL compilation error:
Object 'DISCOVERY_RESULTS' does not exist or not authorized.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Can you please provide the sample code wehre you changed it to "Marketing" and you got the error.

Looks like a permissions issue. I would always include the "EXECUTE AS { CALLER | OWNER }" line in a SP so it's obvious - but check what role the SP is running as and then whether that role has permissions on DISCOVERY_RESULTS

@HimanshuKandpal it's the exact same code as above, just replaced ' LIKE ''%Alternative Credential%''' with ' LIKE ''%Marketing%'''

@NidenK I ran your code with both the Like conditions and did not get any error, from the error message it looks like you don't have access to the object "DISCOVERY_RESULTS", can you please go to the Database explores and see if you are able to see the object DISCOVERY_RESULTS, or just try to run select * from  DISCOVERY_RESULTS , in the worksheet where you are running the modified code.
